# No member named 'replace' in namespace 'std::ranges' message in github actions, even with -std=c++20

Tags: python, c++, cmake, github-actions

I have a python package on github, that runs C++ code with pybind. I figured I'd add github actions to do tests. The build fails on macos-latest (the irony being that it compiles just fine on my local macos machine) with the following message:

```
FAILED: CMakeFiles/sequence_analysis_cpp.dir/src/sequence.cpp.o
  /Applications/Xcode_14.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -DVERSION_INFO=0.1.0 -Dsequence_analysis_cpp_EXPORTS -isystem /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -isystem /private/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-148llo6b/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pybind11/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++20 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode_14.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=12.6 -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/sequence_analysis_cpp.dir/src/sequence.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/sequence_analysis_cpp.dir/src/sequence.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/sequence_analysis_cpp.dir/src/sequence.cpp.o -c /Users/runner/work/sequence_analysis/sequence_analysis/src/sequence.cpp
/Users/runner/work/sequence_analysis/sequence_analysis/src/sequence.cpp:101:18: error: no member named 'replace' in namespace 'std::ranges'
      std::ranges::replace(codon, 'T', 'U');
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
  1 error generated.
```

It does set `-std=gnu++20` as expected. I have `#include <algorithm>` in `sequence.cpp`.

`CMakeLists.txt` has:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
```

`pip.yml` has:

```
name: Pip

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        platform: [windows-latest, macos-latest, ubuntu-latest]
        python-version: ["3.11"]

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.platform }}

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      with:
        submodules: true

    - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}

    - name: Add requirements
      run: python -m pip install --upgrade wheel setuptools biopython numpy

    - name: Build and install
      run: pip install --verbose .[test]

    - name: Test
      run: python -m pytest
```

What am I missing? [Here's the repo](https://github.com/sodiumnitrate/sequence_analysis/tree/main) in case I'm missing some critical info. This issue does not arise with ubuntu-latest, and windows-latest fails for other reasons (that I'm working on).

Comment: It is entirely plausible that the actual reason is the simplest explanation, courtesy of Occam's razor: this specific compiler/platform simply doesn't implement all of C++20 just yet. I remember how, for the longest time, libstdc++ didn't implement `to_chars`/`from_chars` overloads for `float` and `double`, long after g++ recognized `-std=c++17`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Interesting. Would the solution then be to rewrite that part of the code so that it doesn't depend on C++20-only features?

Comment: The [compatibility table](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/cpp/) describes `ranges` to be available only since XCode 14.3.

Comment: XCode is an IDE, not a compiler. I don't see why github would embed XCode (if it's just to get its embedded compiler). It's the compiler version that matters.

Comment: @Fareanor If you look at the line under `FAILED` it says it's trying to use (presumably the command line tools, and thus `clang`, from) `Xcode_14.2.app`. It makes sense because it's not reasonable to expect any random macos machine to have anything other than apple clang (and only if xcode command line tools are installed). What doesn't make sense is that github's "macos-latest" uses a version released in Dec 2022...

Comment: The `-std=c++20` may not mean that the entirety of the specification is supported. There is [this feature matrix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) and sometimes a few fields are missing there. Sometimes it’s as easy as switching to a different compiler (like `clang++` vs `g++` in most cases). Sometimes you need to click in godbolt.org for a while to figure out which compier / version supports your favorite (relatively) new feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `macos-latest` points to `macos-12` which has [Xcode 14.2 as the default](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/macos/macos-12-Readme.md#xcode).

As mentioned in the comments above, according to these compatibility matrices:

- [Xcode: C++ language support](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/cpp/)
- [C++ Reference: Compiler support for C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20)

you need Xcode 14.3 or later.

[`macos-13` supports Xcode 14.3.1 as the default and it also supports Xcode 15.0 as well.](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/macos/macos-13-Readme.md#xcode)

So, simply switching from `macos-latest` (`macos-12`) to `macos-13` should resolve your compiler issue.

With `macos-13` runner, you'll get the Xcode 14.3.1 by default. But, if you want to switch to 15.0, then you can simply set the `DEVELOPER_DIR` environment variable to specify that:

```yaml
    - name: Build and install
      env:
        DEVELOPER_DIR: /Applications/Xcode_15.0.app/Contents/Developer
      run: pip install --verbose .[test]
```

Alternatively, you can use `xcode-select` as well before running any compiler related commands:

```bash
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_15.0.app/Contents/Developer
```

---

Apart from that, your code currently has multiple issues e.g. missing header guards, invalid `int` to `std::string` conversion, undeclared variables, etc. Once your compiler issue is fixed, hopefully you'll be able to fix those easily. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah my C is rusty and C++ is almost nonexistent but I'm working on it :)