# Github actions workflow failing for unit testing iOS app

Tags: ios, github-actions, fastlane

I'm seeing the following in the error logs when the workflow runs:

```
[12:04:39]: Driving the lane 'ios unit_tests' 
[12:04:39]: -----------------------
[12:04:39]: --- Step: run_tests ---
[12:04:39]: -----------------------
[12:04:39]: Resolving Swift Package Manager dependencies...
[12:04:39]: $ xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -scheme CICDDemo -project ./CICDDemo.xcodeproj
[12:04:40]: ▸ Command line invocation:
[12:04:40]: ▸     /Applications/Xcode_14.2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -scheme CICDDemo -project ./CICDDemo.xcodeproj
[12:04:40]: ▸ User defaults from command line:
[12:04:40]: ▸     IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
[12:04:45]: ▸ --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
[12:04:45]: ▸ { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
[12:04:45]: ▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
[12:04:45]: ▸ resolved source packages: 
[12:04:45]: $ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -scheme CICDDemo -project ./CICDDemo.xcodeproj
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
[12:04:48]: Command timed out after 3 seconds on try 1 of 4, trying again with a 6 second timeout...
2023-10-13 12:04:50.353 xcodebuild[5556:27100] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.InterfaceBuilderBuildSupport.PlatformDefinition
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
2023-10-13 12:04:52.099 xcodebuild[5584:27154] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.InterfaceBuilderBuildSupport.PlatformDefinition

[12:04:54]: ▸ Loading...
[12:04:56]: ▸ 2023-10-13 12:04:56.353 xcodebuild[5618:27277] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/3s/vfzpb5r51gs6y328rmlgzm7c0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2023-13-10_12-04-0056.xcresult
[12:04:57]: ▸ xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
[12:04:57]: ▸       { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BDC3DCB4-9BC6-4DBF-93FD-312192818135 }
[12:04:57]: ▸   Available destinations for the "CICDDemo" scheme:
[12:04:57]: ▸       { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
[12:04:57]: ▸       { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
2023-10-13 12:04:56.353 xcodebuild[5618:27277] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/3s/vfzpb5r51gs6y328rmlgzm7c0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2023-13-10_12-04-0056.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BDC3DCB4-9BC6-4DBF-93FD-312192818135 }

    Available destinations for the "CICDDemo" scheme:
        { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
[12:04:57]: Exit status: 70
```

My workflow `.yml` file has the following:

```
name: Unit Tests
# This workflow is triggered on pushes & pull requests to the repository.
on:
  push:
    branches: [main, develop, feature/*]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, develop, feature/*]
  
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build and test
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v1
    
    - name: Bundle install
      run: bundle install

    - name: Setup Xcode version #https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-xcode-version
      uses: maxim-lobanov/setup-xcode@v1
      with:
        xcode-version: latest-stable #
      
    - name: Run unit tests
      run: bundle exec fastlane unit_tests
```

Finally my fastfile contains this:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Description of what the lane does"
  lane :custom_lane do
    # add actions here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions
  end

  # Unit tests lane
  lane :unit_tests do
    run_tests(build_for_testing: true,
              scheme: "CICDDemo",
              only_testing: "CICDDemo",
              device: "iPhone 14")
  end
end
```

The project that I'm running this for is built with Xcode 14.3 with deployment target 16.4.

Based on the error logs, it seems like I need to specify a destination whether simulator or device for the tests to run on but I'm not sure how to specify it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77201434/7670262. Try: `runs-on: macos-13`

Comment: That fixed the issue. Strangely, in the logs I see that it used Xcode 15 which afaik requires macOS14. I'm not sure how that worked out, but thank you bhai and good luck for the WC match tomo.

Comment: You're welcome! :) In your logs above, Xcode version is 14.2 i.e. `/Applications/Xcode_14.2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild`. As you mentioned in your description that you're using 14.3, the first thing was to configure that correctly. With `macos-13`, it was fixed. BTW, you don't need to use `maxim-lobanov/setup-xcode` anymore as the required Xcode version is already there. Marking it as duplicate of above thread. Cheers!

Comment: I did not know that. Lots to learn! :)